# Proper installation of a supply line escutcheon

Tags: plumbing

I have built 4 houses and finished 3 rehabs including the plumbing without figuring out how to properly install the supply line escutcheons.

I think sticking it to the wall with putty is tacky, no pun intended, and part of the pipe between the escutcheon/flange and the cutoff valve still show.

How do you install the escutcheon snugly and avoid showing any of the ugly pex pipe?

Answer (score 1):

Use copper stub outs for pex.  Like this:

[https://www.amazon.com/Sharkbite-25094A-Copper-Elbow-Bracket/dp/B016Q4OAKY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B016Q4OAKY)

It is very difficult to finish pex coming out of a wall nicely.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVD-ZMC2jA0

Comment: ...if you think PEX is uniquely ugly, anyway. Or put it in a cabinet and don't look at it...

Comment: Thank you for the info.  Good idea.